# How can I create a XML file using JAVA

Tags: java

I would like to create a XML file in this format:

```
<msgs>
    <msg>
        <type>sense</type>
        <cid>168</cid>
        <ip>192.168.140.150</ip>
        <errs/>
        <id>002EC0FEFF83EA97</id>
        <sensors>
            <sensor sid='002EC0FEFF8FFF27' desc='' batt='6.60' sig='-55' scount='0' rdate='15/05/2015 21:47:04' mdate='18/04/2016 08:06:25' />
            <sensor sid='002EC0FEFF8FFF27' desc='' batt='6.60' sig='-55' scount='0' rdate='15/05/2015 21:47:04' mdate='18/04/2016 08:07:25' />
            <sensor sid='002EC0FEFF8FFF27' desc='' batt='6.60' sig='-55' scount='0' rdate='15/05/2015 21:47:04' mdate='18/04/2016 08:08:25' />
        </sensors>
    </msg>
</msgs>
```

Once the XML is created, I want to save this file in a folder

Comment: I have to handle the multiple attributes in XML

Answer (score 0):

Using "JAXB" you can convert java object to xml and then write it to file.

Sample code for setting values to Student object and printing out put to console

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

Student object = new Student();
object.setId(11);
object.setName("Bob");
m.marshal(object, System.out);
```

Comment: you have to explain the annotation of your classes to provide the correct answer - bring an example?